# Unable to get a connection in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've been trying to connect to a hosted runtime on Google Colab as usual. Until now, it worked perfectly, but for some reason right now everytime I press 'CONNECT' it shows up 'No backends available' and doesn't connect to a run time. Tried it in incognito mode as well and also tried different browsers but still this problem persists.
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GY7d.png)

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9nlI.png)

Comment: Have you been running any notebooks that do things like cryptocurrency mining? The [FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) mentions that this may result in being banned from the service.

Comment: nothing like that, just a simple classification program using neural networks